# Change github checked in name

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Using intelliJ I import my project to github from intelliJ menu:

> VCS > Import into version control > Share project on github.

I'm using two computers, mac win pc with intelliJ and git. When checking in code into github with my mac using intelliJ "share project on github" function, it displays my full name. But when checking in code from my win pc it displays my github username.

How do I change or specify the name to be displayed in the log/announce header/commit logs of the github repository?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working now by deleting git remotes from intelliJ menu:

> VCS > Git > origin.

And also to be sure, I deleted the repo in github web.

And also re-add github username from intelliJ menu:

> preferences > version control > GitHub > - to delete and + to add and
>   set to default with checkbox.

Then I pushed to git again using intelliJ menu:

> VCS > import into version control > "share project on github"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name for the commit logs using this command inside your git project:

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
```

And, if you want configure the same name for all your project you can add the --global attribute to the line, like this:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Next commits that you do will appears with same name. You need to check the same in Git configurations on IntelliJ

Comment: I tried that but didn't work when sharing the project to github from intelliJ it still displays my full name. But only on the mac. On pc it shows my github username